# What will be nature of n?

Tags: calculus

If the function $f(x) = x \, (x^2-4)^n \, (x^2-x+1)$ assumes local minimum at $n=2m$, then what will be $n$?

(a) odd number

(b) even number

(c) odd prime number

(d) multiple of $4$

(n is a natural number)

I got stuck.  Please help!

Comment: What a weird question.

Comment: I think there must be some typo, because I don't see how a function of $x$ should have a minimum at a given value of $n$.

Comment: Even I think so @Ian...should I delete this question?Or should I wait a bit?

Answer (score 2):

As I graph that function for $n=2,4,6$, each time I get a local minimum at $x=2$. (At $n=1$ the minimum is non-integral, at $n=3$ the minimum is at $x=1$, and at $n=5$ the minimum is non-integral.) Therefore, the answer seems to be that $n=2$, so (b) an even number.

Let's try it analytically just for $n=2$. Since $n=2m$, $n$ is even, so answers (a) and (c) which say $n$ is odd are obviously wrong.

For $n=2$, I get

$$f(x)=x^7-x^6-9x^5+8x^4+24x^3-16x^2-16x$$

$$f'(x)=7x^6-6x^5-45x^4+32x^3+72x^2-32x-16$$
$$=(x-2)(x+2)(7x^4-6x^3-17x^2+8x+4)$$

So clearly $f'(2)=0$.

$$f''(x)=42x^5-30x^4-180x^3+96x^2+144x-32$$

and

$$f''(2)=64$$

so $f(x)$ is convex up at $x=2$. Combining that, we get that $f(x)$ has a minimum (local or global) at $x=2$.

The only answer provided that fits this is (b) an even number.

Note that we did not prove this is always true, just for one particular case. But given the nature of the problem, this is good enough.

Comment: if $$f(x)=(x-a)^{2k}g(x) \rightarrow x=a $$ is minimum or maximum ,
 $x=a $is min when $g(a)>0\\$  
$\\x=a$ is max when $g(a)<0$ $$k=1,2,3,4,...$$